# What distinguishes the files that belong in /usr/share from those that belong in /usr?

Tags: files, filesystem

What distinguishes the files that belong in **/usr/share** from those that belong in **/usr**?  In fact, how did the notion of the **share** directory become enshrined in Unix at all (historical question)?

Answer (score 1):

/usr/share according to the FHS: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.11.html

> The /usr/share hierarchy is for all read-only architecture independent data files.
>   This hierarchy is intended to be shareable among all architecture platforms of a given OS; thus, for example, a site with i386, Alpha, and PPC platforms might maintain a single /usr/share directory that is centrally-mounted. Note, however, that /usr/share is generally not intended to be shared by different OSes or by different releases of the same OS.

So it has as specific usage.

/usr though has so many different purposes and  it is hard to compare it to a subset of itself. .